# geom_ribbon for just one line in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that is a result of a `rbind` between 2 dataframes that do not have the same amount of columns and thus `NA` values are introduced, here is a glance of it. I'm not sure if I should share it here since it's quite long.

```
> dat
     overlaps     N std se_of_mean margin.error upper_boundary lower_boundary             peaks
  1:        0 38232  NA         NA           NA             NA             NA      eprint_peaks
  2:        1  1191  NA         NA           NA             NA             NA      eprint_peaks
  3:        2   533  NA         NA           NA             NA             NA      eprint_peaks
  4:        3   360  NA         NA           NA             NA             NA      eprint_peaks
  5:        4   225  NA         NA           NA             NA             NA      eprint_peaks
 ---                                                                                           
102:       69     1   0          0            0              0              0 mean_random_peaks
103:       76     1   0          0            0              0              0 mean_random_peaks
104:       79     1   0          0            0              1              1 mean_random_peaks
105:       81     1   0          0            0              0              0 mean_random_peaks
106:       94     1   0          0            0              0              0 mean_random_peaks
```

So the columns in common between these 2 dataframes are `overlaps` and `N`. The `peaks` columns is my `grouping` variable in `ggplot2`. Now I plot two lines like this:

```
ggplot(data=dat,aes(x=overlaps,y=log(N),color=peaks)) + 
  geom_line()
```

And get this graph:

[image]

So far so good, everything is quite simple. The problem arises when I want to build a confidence interval for the `blue` line called `mean_random_peaks` like so:

```
ggplot(data=dat,aes(x=overlaps,y=log(N),color=peaks)) + 
  geom_line()+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower_boundary,ymax=upper_boundary))
```

Please note that `upper_boundary` `lower_boundary` is `NA` for all `eprint_peaks` because I don't basically want to plot any confidence interval for this line and initial dataframe in the first place did not even have these columns, for `mean_random_peaks` it's all good I do have values to plot for `upper_boundary` `lower_boundary` and this should be used as shades of grey to the blue line i.e. the typical image of a `geom_ribbon` produces.

The problem is that I get this warning when plotting:

```
Warning message:
In max(ids, na.rm = TRUE) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

and my plot looks awful:

I think ggplot is trying to get `geom_ribbon` for both lines and as `eprint_peaks` has only `NA` things gets distorted.
[image]

Comment: What if, for `eprint_peaks` rows, `upper_boundary` values will equal `lower_boundary` values, but instead `NA` they will both equal the value on y-axis, i.e., `log(N)`? This means that the confidence ribbon for `eprint_peaks` line will be of no width. Can you change the values in relevant `dat` columns to reflect my suggestion, then try to plot again?

Comment: yes you are right, this was my silly mistake.